JSDoc and Documentation.js weird $0. output
I'm currently writing the documentation for my codebase, but I'm getting weird output when trying to unpack an Object in JSDoc to describe its properties.
/**
 * Foundational class for sending requests and managing responses.
 */
class AjaxRequest {
    /**
     * Constructs a new instance with the given configuration.
     *
     * @constructor
     * @param {Object} config - The configuration object.
     * @param {string} config.endpoint - The endpoint URL for the request.
     * @param {string} config.method - The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g., 'GET', 'POST').
     * @param {string} config.contentType - The content type of the request (e.g., 'application/json').
     * @param {Object} config.payload - The payload to be sent.
     */
    constructor({ endpoint, method, contentType, payload }) {
    //code here
    }
}

This produces

Why do I get $0. ?
Documentation was generated using: documentation build ajax.js -f html -o docs
I am using the latest version of Documentation.js

This happens only with the constructor. If I change the constructor to a normal function, it works. However, the issue still remains, and I cannot generate my documentation.
